# Highchart column animation when adding new column

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts

I'm trying to make a simple bar chart that updates every 5 seconds using highchart. Below is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
                <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
                <script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
        <script>

                Highcharts.chart('container', {
                        chart: {
                                type: 'column'
                        },
                        title: {
                                text: 'Activity Count per Model'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                                categories: [],
                                crosshair: true,
                                title: {
                                        text: 'Model'
                                }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                                min: 0,
                                title: {
                                        text: 'Activity Count'
                                }
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                                column: {
                                        animation: true,
                                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                                        borderWidth: 0
                                }
                        },
                        series: [{
                                name: 'Count',
                                data: []

                        }]
                });

                setInterval(function(){
                        $.getJSON("http://localhost/getdata.php", function(data){
                                $('#container').highcharts().series[0].setData(data.value,true);
                                $('#container').highcharts().xAxis[0].setCategories(data.model);
                        });
                }, 5000);

        </script>
</html>
```

The data returned from JSON call:

```
{"model":["a","aa","aaa","aaaa","aab","b","c","d","e"],"value":[40,20,70,40,70,20,30,40,50]}
```

Right now functionally the code works fine (chart shows up with the data updated every 5 second). The problem is that if the chart updates with new column, there's no animation on it. But if the existing data is updated without adding new column, there's animation in it (column growing up / shrinking, other column adjust if axis change). How do I enable the animation when new column is inserted into the chart?

Answer (score 0):

In that case there are different possibilities how the chart should be animated. So you should consider what animation you'd want to.

From [setData()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.setData) docs:

> When the updated data is the same length as the existing data, points will be updated by default, and animation visualizes how the points are changed.

IN your case you can split your data in two parts - the new point and the rest data. The rest data can be set with `setData()` - and you will preserve the animation because the old and new data have same length. And the point can be added with animation via [addPoint()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.addPoint).

```
$('#button').click(function () {
  const data = new Array(12).fill(2)
  chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories.concat('13'), false);
  chart.series[0].setData(data);
  chart.series[0].addPoint(40, true, false, true);
});
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lqy2e42h/

Comment: It seems to me that this solution does not address the actual problem, which is the new bar not being animated. This just animates everything around the new bar...

Comment: To animate the new bar - there is a need of an old value, so the animation has start and end point - this is what  point.update() animation needs. addPoint() animation does not animate the point in this case but rather the axis. Anyway, It can be still achieved by adding a dummy point  - http://jsfiddle.net/Lqy2e42h/1/

Comment: Makes sense. It'd be nice if the chart could handle the logic of creating a start point for the new data, then animate it, but your solution of adding a dummy point is a pretty usable work around. Thanks.